# Visual Studio C++ performance vs Intel C++ compiler 15

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intel, compiler-optimization

Visual Studio 2015 has got a lot of changes on the C++ compiler side and I'm looking for a benchmark/performance comparison between the Intel C++ compiler and Visual Studio 2015 !

About performance, I mean the performance of the generated code, something like this : https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers/iss

Is there an interest to use the Intel C++ compiler  ? Will it produce faster code ?

Thanks

Comment: I say the difference will be application dependent and certainly not as clear as the marketing suggests.

Comment: The top 4 factors that affect code speed, in order, are Programmer, Developer, Coder and Compiler.  You can't get a warranty, you must try it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Few year ago, i did some tests on a mac-pro with intel proc. 
Results:

1. icc+linux
2. vc+win
3. icc+win
4. gcc+linux

icc+linux was the very best.
vc+win, icc+win were pretty close.

*Explanation:* the more the software editor can exploit assertion on the system+hardware, the more it can design a compiler generating fast running code.

- Intel is the best because it can exploit its processor and the system (open source).
- VC under windows works great too, they know their OS.

Now, this depends of the kind of software. If your program will load a lot of data from disk the best will certainly be vc+win (they have great implementation of internal buffers...). If your program is very multithreaded, icc+linux is gonna win for sure. These are only 2 examples I can talk about because I tested these use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I compared ICC and VC on Windows, and they were very close in terms of performance. I was able to make ICC beat VC only by using the "profile guided optimization" feature.